# Bootstrap Scrollspy inconsistent behavior

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I'm confused with scrollspy behavior i implemented to a website. Problem is that whenever i scroll to the DOM (scrolling within the DOM height) active state to a menu is not consistent. It sometimes not active and sometimes it is active. It has a smooth scroll function that whenever a menu is clicked it will scroll to that element and would activate the scrollspy whenever reached a target element. Problem is it sometimes activate, and sometimes don't. There are 4 navigation correspond to 4 sections of blocks. As i click to those navigation, it sometimes have an active state as reached the target element and sometimes don't and not even activate in a patterned way. If someone could explain me or help me fix this bug that would be very much appreciated :)